# VIsual Studio with GIT - separate windows for changes and sync

Tags: git, visual-studio, window, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015. 
I have it connected to my Github repository and using it fine.
The nature of GIT is that you first commit changes, and then push to github.
In VS, there is a single 'Team Explorer' window. From there I can click the 'Changes' button and commit them, then there is a link to sync.
It then switches to the sync window and to go back to my changes, I have to click the 'Home' button and then the 'Changes' button again. This is annoying.

I'd like to have a window for changes and a window for sync. I'm aware of command line tools to do the same and that will be my fall back if this isn't resolvable but my question is purely about the windows in VS.

Is it possible to separate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These dialogues can not be split, but what you can do is to enable commands to go to them directly, which will at least reduce the clicks.  You can also enable commit+sync or commit+push on one button if you like, but if you like to do it in one operation, you can do a commit&sync directly from the changes window.

[image]

You could do that on the last commit, and then it will push all your commits up to then.  It will end on the sync tab though, so the next tip will help a bit there:
You can add more commands to the toolbar (or any menu, but I guess the toolbar is best).  Go to Tools/Customize, and choose the Commands tab. Then select Add Command... , then select Team, and you will find a lot of team explorer commands in the list.  You can then  add as many of them as you like.

[image]

In the screenshot above, you see the direct commands Commit, Commit and Push, and Commit and Sync.  To solve your specific question, further down you find these:

[image]

"Go to Git Changes" (2-below) takes you to the Changes hub,and "Go to Git Synchronization" (1-below) takes you to the Sync hub.

I just added them to the standard bar, but note you can add them to anything, to make it look better:

[image]

3,4 and 5 is the Git Commit and Sync, Git Commit and Push, and Git commit - probably not a good idea to overcrowd it, but just to show the point.